# Flutter: AudioPlayer Stop Multiple Sound

Tags: flutter, dart

I use AudioPlayers package.

I have 2 different sounds. When user clicks to buttons (Button1) , both of sounds start playing.

But there is another button which calling "Button2" has to stop all of the sounds at once. I wrote this :

```
  AudioCache playerCache = new AudioCache(); 

  AudioPlayer player = new AudioPlayer();

  void _playFile(String sound) async {
    player = await playerCache.play(sound);
  }

  void cancelPlay() {
    print("stop");
    playSounds.removeRange(0, playSounds.length);
    player.stop();
    player.stop();
  }
```

However , when user click Button2 , it only stops the last sound. I want that to stop all of the sounds. How to do that ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. configure the `fixedPlayer` property on your AudioCache so it always uses the same player.
2. if you don't, every time you call `playerCache.play` it will return a new instance of Audio Players, so you must keep track of them on a list and then you can stop all by iterating this list.